# Different between publishApkNameRelease and publishNameRelease CI/CD

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-play-publisher

iam trying to publish new version of the app using this `plugin: 'com.github.triplet.play'`

and when i ran `gradlew app:publishApkRelease`

i got this error message

> - What went wrong: Task 'publishApkRelease' not found in project ':app'. Some candidates are:  'publishApkTestRelease', 'publishApkTestRelease'.

i want to know what is the Different also how do i specify the description for this uploaded version ?

Comment: is spilt apk enabled?

Comment: no but im using product flavors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have product flavors. To find available tasks, run ./gradlew tasks and look under the publishing section.

```
./gradlew tasks
```

Here run the appropriate task for your product flavor.

Also try ./gradlew

```
./gradlew app:publishApkRelease
```

You are facing this issue as task "publishApkRelease" is not found at root project.

Refer this for more: https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher#task-organization

Also, if above doesn't work you can find a solution here https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher/issues/81